# RDP Disconnected! Error Code: 2308 Error Description: Socket closed

Tags: rdp

We restarted our Windows 2003 server R2 last night (09/27) and since that day we can not connect through RDP.

We have this kind of error using mRemote:

```
RDP Disconnected! Error Code: 2308 Error Description: Socket closed
```

Using Remote Desktop Connection we have :

```
This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.
```

Does anybody knows How to bound TCP to only one NIC ? could you please give me the path or command? Is there any command line I could use to do it?

Thank you for your help

Sabine (Houston,TX)

Comment: A solution to the same issue is proposed here: http://serverfault.com/questions/49428/rdp-remote-desktop-disconnected-error-2308-socket-closed

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a similar issue, error 2308.

How I fixed it:

1. I've opened services.msc on my machine.
2. Connected via RPC to the server with non-working RDP.
3. Restarted service "Terminal Service" and dependent service "Terminal Service UserMode Port Redirector".
4. Connected to RDP successfully.

Note: on Windows Server 2008 (and probably 2012), these services are called *Remote Desktop Services* and *Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector*. Another user reported being ableto fix the issue by just restarting the port redirector service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but to only use TCP/IP on one NIC you would uncheck "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" in the network settings for any other NIC other than the one you want to have connected.

Not sure how that answers your RDP question - but as far as RDP goes you should check the server log. Either Terminal Services (RDP) server is down, there could be a firewall issue, or there could be a licensing issue that would cause that error.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Do I need to restart the server after the modification?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the server was actually restarted? Maybe it the shutdown process hanged for some reason. Have you looked at the event log and seen the startup events?

Comment: the server was restarted. My colleague came earlier this morning and restarted again the DC server. Now it works. The server displays on the screen and RDP connection works. We look at the events log but nothing relevant has been saved. weird hein! We contacted Dell support and they shipped us a new Motherboard in case the server goes bad again. Thanks for your help and analysis guys.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this plenty of times on 2003 servers, for some reason after a reboot the RDP service is not responding correctly even though it's running and another reboot will solve it... not the kind of solution one would want to hear though ^^

Answer (score 0):

Also had this Issue. Fixed it by activating "Keep-Alive-Connection". Follow this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216783

Answer (score 0):

may be you are not connecting to remote session through administrator account. if it is so , please add your accout to remote session option in my computer/property
you will be able to connect to the remote connection

Answer (score 0):

I connected `services.msc` from my server, and then on top left there is:

1. Services(Local)
2. Right click and select `Connect to another computer`
3. Enter problem server IP address
4. Click OK.

And restart the RDP Services that are responsible to connect to system

1. Remote Desktop Services
2. Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector

Answer (score -1):

You should check the log or use application like Wireshark to check why it happened.